# How to remove json data flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

My Json

```
[{"id":"2911","nama":"Abcd1","url":"myUrl"},{"id":"2910","nama":"Abcd2","url":"myUrl"},{"id":"2911","nama":"Abcd3","url":"myUrl"},{"id":"2549","nama":"Abcd4","url":"myUrl"}]
```

My Code Try

```
  var fromCache2 = '''$fromCache1''';
  List dataList = [];
  final jsonData = json.decode(fromCache2);
  print('Last Json : ' + jsonData.toString());
  jsonData.forEach((element) {
    print('element ' + element['id'].toString());
    dataList.removeWhere((e) => element['id'] == id);
    dataList.add(element);
  });
  print('New Data : ' + dataList.toString());
```

i want to delete data where "id":"2910", but

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I have added the code in the question

Comment: before ask please **search** on **"stackoverflow"**. already anyone answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeWhere` should work, example:

```
void main() {
  var jsonData = [
    {"id": "2911", "nama": "Abcd1", "url": "myUrl"},
    {"id": "2910", "nama": "Abcd2", "url": "myUrl"},
    {"id": "2911", "nama": "Abcd3", "url": "myUrl"},
    {"id": "2549", "nama": "Abcd4", "url": "myUrl"}
  ];

  jsonData.removeWhere((element) => element["id"] == "2911");

  print(jsonData);
}
```

In your code, it should look like this:

```
final jsonData = json.decode(fromCache2);
jsonData.removeWhere((element) => element['id'] == id);
```

No need to use a temporary dataList variable.

Comment: Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, String>>')

Comment: I updated the code, but you just need to remove type annotation for this line: final jsonData = json.decode(fromCache2);

Answer (score 0):

You could use `where` to filter your `jsonData`:

```dart
const jsonData = [
  { "id": "2909", "nama": "Abcd1", "url": "myUrl" },
  { "id": "2910", "nama": "Abcd2", "url": "myUrl" },
  { "id": "2911", "nama": "Abcd3", "url": "myUrl" },
];

void main() {
  print(jsonData.where((row) => row['id'] != '2910').toList());
}
```

## Console log

```
[{id: 2909, nama: Abcd1, url: myUrl}, {id: 2911, nama: Abcd3, url: myUrl}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you get index from List or JsonData.
Then you can do **read** , **delete** or **update**.

```
  final index = jsonData.indexWhere((element) => element['id'] == '2549');
```

//remove index data

```
  jsonData.removeAt(index);
```

// update index data

```
  jsonData[index]['id'] = '2550';
```